# working with database in MVC

Tags: php, database, oop, model-view-controller

I'm trying to work with database, do queries and so..

Database class where is the connection

```
class Database { 

    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = '';

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }
    function connect() {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=university', $this->user, $this->password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES CP1251'));
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
    }

    function selectQuery( $sql ) {
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

IndexController

```
require_once 'application/models/Database.php';

class IndexController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->db = new Database();
        $data = $this->db->selectQuery('SELECT * FROM students');
        $this->view->render('index','template',$data);
    }
}
```

In this controller i connect to database and do query, then sending it to view

View class

```
class View {

    function render($content_view, $template_view, $data = null) {
        /*
        if(is_array($data)) {
            // преобразуем элементы массива в переменные
            extract($data);
        }
        */

        $content = $content_view.'.php';
        include 'application/views/'.$template_view.'.php';
    }
}
```

The task is display the result in my view, how can i do that?

Please help :)

Thanks

Comment: What framework are you using? Zend, Codeigniter or Your own ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `selectQuery` does not return anything, let it `return $this->stmt` or anything you would like.

In the file `$template_view.php` you can access the `$data` variable as long the template is a PHP file.

I would prefer setting your variables for the template like this;

```
// Add a general class
class Data {
    private $binds = array();
    public function bind($key, $value) { 
        $this->binds[$key] = $value; 
    }
    public function getAll() { 
        return $this->binds; 
    }
}

// Add this in the controller
$data = new Data();
$data->bind('students', $this->model('students')->readAll());
$this->view->render('index','template',$data->getAll());
```

And [extract](https://www.php.net/extract) the variables within the view.
Then you can access `$students` from your template file.

Comment: Yes but how i display it? i need to fetch it someway, how i do it in my example?

Comment: I'm not understanding your questions correctly. Try adding `var_dump($data)` to your template file.

Comment: What is the DataObject class?

Comment: I did, it displays NULL

Comment: And if you do `var_dump($data)` in your Controller, is it also `NULL`? I'll elaborate the object.

Comment: Yes, but if i write in my controller while($row = $this->db->stmt->fetch($data)){
   var_dump($row);
  } it works

Comment: Your function `selectQuery` does not return anything!

Comment: I did it like this - $q = $this->db->selectQuery('SELECT * FROM students');
  $data = $this->db->stmt->fetch($q); Then passed $data to template, now i can display the result. But i can display only one row, because of $this->db->stmt->fetch(), how should i do then?

Comment: You should use `fetchAll`

Comment: If it works now, please accept the answer :) We can use the Stackoverflow-chat for this. Putting your Skype name in public is generally not a good idea.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation

Comment: Post it in a seperate question or post your Skype, I'll add you.